# Error when translating geocode to text address using ggmap package

Tags: r, ggmap, geocode

I want to add a column that has the text address of every shop listed in a data.table based upon the shop's geocode (longitude and latitude) using `ggmap`'s function: `revgeocode`.

To do so, I have a data.table with the following information:

```
dt
shop_id    LON        LAT
Shop1     -86.82651  21.15774
Shop2     -86.82663  21.17349
Shop3     -86.84672  21.14235
```

I would like to use the following `for` loop to add a column that has the address of every shop in readable text:

```
dt$address <- "TEXT"
i = nrow(dt)
for (i in c(1:nrow(dt))) {
    dt$address[i] <- revgeocode( as.numeric( dt[i,c("LON","LAT"] ),
                                 output = "address", source = "google")
}
```

Unfortunately, the loop is not entirely working. I am getting the follwoing warnign messages for certain geocodes:

> 1: In revgeocode(as.numeric(sucs[i, c("LONGITUD", "LATITUD")]), output
>   = "address",  :   reverse geocode failed - bad location? location = "-86.8266333"reverse geocode failed - bad location? location =
>   "21.1734889"

In theory, these codes should all be working, as the shops' geocodes were pulled directly from Google Earth. Has anyone figured out why some goecodes return as `bad location` warning?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem running your loop (I corrected the syntax):

```
for( i in 1:nrow(dt) ) {
  dt$address[i] <- revgeocode( as.numeric(dt[i, c("LON","LAT")]), output = "address" )
}

> dt
  shop_id       LON      LAT
1   Shop1 -86.82651 21.15774
2   Shop2 -86.82663 21.17349
3   Shop3 -86.84672 21.14235
                                                                                  address
1                                                   Av Coba 9, 22, 77500 Cancún, Q.R., Mexico
2                                     Carr. Tulum - Cancún 3d, 63, 77513 Cancún, Q.R., Mexico
3 Av Kohunlich Smza 50 Mza 27 Lotes 102 103 y 104, Capistrano, 50, 77533 Cancún, Q.R., Mexico
```

Probably the error was returned by the Google API for failing to return the address after a certain time, witch is common. You can work around it by adding a conditional loop to make it keep trying until all addresses are returned:

```
dt$address <- NA

while( anyNA(dt$address) ) {
  for( i in 1:nrow(dt) ) {
    if( is.na(dt[i,"address"]) ) {
      dt$address[i] <- revgeocode( as.numeric(dt[i, c("LON","LAT")]), output = "address" )
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: PS: There's no need for the `i = nrow(dt)` line

Comment: Thank you Carlos!